# What checksum is it and how does it work? [Checksum 32bit]

Tags: c, checksum

I'm trying to implement the checksum from the WinHex program, in WinHex and in 010 editor its called

> Checksum Uint 32bit

For example, we calculate the checksum of 32byte (represented in HEX) data:

> 1122334455667788991122334455667711223344556677889911223344556677

The WinHex gives us checksum32 value:

> EE65DE86

I was thinking it's just about summing each byte to the previous one:

```
    unsigned char checksum(unsigned char data[]){
        unsigned char sum = 0;
        int i;
        for(i=0; sizeof(data); i++){
            sum += data[i];
        }
        return -sum;
       }
```

I tried it, and it gave me the wrong checksum. It is clearly not crc, maybe its Adler or Fletcher or smh else, it's so many checksums variation that kinda difficult to find correct one

Comment: Given your code uses the `unsigned` keyword, can we infer that your `[c#]` tag is wrong?

Comment: @Llama yes, sorry, fiex it

Comment: [This (page 15)](https://www.fss.jp/wp-content/uploads/WinHex_fss_soft0502.pdf) says it's just a sum of all the bytes, but in practice I'm not getting that result either.

Comment: why `return ~sum + 1;` when it's just the same as `return -sum;`

Comment: @phuclv fixed it but result the same

Comment: @Llama this is what i have found in some ubuntu source  **This is a 32-bit checksum, and is defined as follows:**   s = sum of all bytes;
                   r = s % 2^16 + (s % 2^32) / 2^16;
                   cksum = (r % 2^16) + r / 2^16;

Comment: @Llama code seems strange, what is %

Comment: The modulo operator, it returns the remainder of the division.

Comment: @busybee doesnt give me correct result

Comment: From the value of the result it is obvious that is cannot just be sum of all 8 bit values. If you are talking about [this tool](https://documentation.help/WinHex-X-Ways/topic7.htm) it mentions " is simply the sum of all bytes in a file, calculated either on an 8-bit, a 16-bit, a 32-bit, or a 64-bit accumulator" Therefore I would try to add up the data grouped as 32 bit values. Especially the description you already copied to the question: "Checksum Uint 32bit" indicates that you should not use single bytes.

Comment: How does your code from "some Ubuntu source" fit to WinHex tool?

Comment: @Gerhardh because as i think checksum 32bit has the same algorithm, in spite of  application or operating system

Comment: It says "**a** 32 bit checksum", not "**the only** 32 bit checksum". CRC32 is also "**a** 32 bit checksum"

Comment: @Gerhardh I have checked the uint 8bit checksum, and have summed all bytes to each other, it gave me the correct answer, seems like you are right about int32 checksum connecting two bytes into integer and summing them up, as I understand if the value is 11223344, it means it will be 2 integers 0x1122 and 0x3344 need to try it out

Comment: I would suggest to take 4 byte pieces, not 2 bytes.

Comment: "I tried it, and it gave me the wrong checksum." Post true code and results.

Comment: IMO, the EE65DE86 is the checksum of 32-bit values of the file, and the file is not the hex of "112233...".  Post file length.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica its true result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function seems to never returns
it's an infinite loop, or **crush**
`i` keeps on increasing till overlaps
besides `sizeof(data)` is 4, `data` is a pointer

```
unsigned char checksum(unsigned char data[]){
    unsigned char sum = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; sizeof(data); i++){ // equivalent for(i=0; 4; i++), for(i=0; true; i++)
        sum += data[i];
    }
    return -sum;
   }
```

also we need `data` length

```
unsigned char checksum(unsigned char data[], int data_length){  //<-- added data_length
    int sum = 0; // <-- int instead of unsigned char
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<data_length; i++){  //  as long as i is less than data_length
        sum += data[i];
    }
    return -sum;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

At least this problem:

`sizeof(data)` below is the size of a pointer and not 0 --> Infinite loop.

```
unsigned char checksum(unsigned char data[]){
    unsigned char sum = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; sizeof(data); i++){
        sum += data[i];
    }
    return -sum;
   }
```

Function only returns value 0-0xFF, never 0xEE65DE86

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, thanks to Gerhardh, we need to convert 4bytes into int32 then sum it up

```
unsigned int checksum( int  data[])
{
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    int i;
    int size;
        
    for(i=0; sizeof(data); i++) {
        sum += data[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Posted code is an infinite loop.  Even fixed, data does not add up to EE65DE86.